# How to get location of all the app user and show it on map

Tags: java, android, webserver

I want to show the location of all the app user on a map. How to get the location of a specific app user. Do we need a webserver to communicate or do it without a server? Any idea or link to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the location of each user to server using `GPS`, and get that location from `API` and show markers on the map

Comment: can we do it without a server? if not which server should i use and how.i am new on android development @mdDroid

Comment: @MuhammadRaza did you have any API integration in your application

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the location of each user to server using fused Api and get current location and save it to server by using web service and for showing markers on map use another web service for getting all locations.